# SVG - why are there margins around my SVG even though I'm not setting margins?

Tags: css, html, svg

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/jononomo/yG45J/7/

```
<div class='div-for-svg'>
    <svg id='blue-border-svg'></svg>
    <svg id='green-border-svg'></svg>    
</div>

.div-for-svg {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#blue-border-svg {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#green-border-svg {
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I want the two SVG elements to be above and below each other, with no white space in-between them.  As it stands now, there is clear space below the bottom blue border of the top SVG element, and above the top green border of the bottom SVG element.  How can I get rid of this space, and why is it there in the first place?  Also, do the SVG elements come with default height and width?
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per default your `svg` elements have `display:inline`, so they behave like any other inline element – with normal images it would be the same: space for the under-lengths of possible text content on the same “line” is reserved. (And for `img` this problem has already been discussed lots of times …)

Using `vertical-align:top` (http://jsfiddle.net/yG45J/9/) or `display:block` (http://jsfiddle.net/yG45J/10/) solves this problem.